# Problem with LED blink program on Pi

Tags: gpio, python, led, pi-b+, board-leds

I am completely new to RPi and stuck unexpectedly. 
I am trying to create a simple python program to make my LED blink.
Here are the two programs which are giving same outputs on terminal when I checked the status with *gpio readall*

## 1.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT)

for i in range(10):
        print "all good"
        GPIO.output(4,True)
        time.sleep(5)
        GPIO.output(4,False)
        time.sleep(5)


GPIO.cleanup()
```

2.

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

led = LED(4)
print(led.value)
led.off()
i=0
while i<10:
    print("hi test")
    led.on()
    sleep(1)
    led.off()
    sleep(1)
    i+=1
```

When I check my LED circuits, it seems all good with 3.3V... however, when I change the pin to any other one LED is not blinking. In fact, nothing is happening.

Please help!
Pin: 6 and 7th. The red wire is to ground. Resistor: 560 Ohm!

*I am using Pi 1 B+ with raspbian stretch; Python 2.7 and 3.5*

[image: circuilt]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are asking us to guess how the LED is connected.  That is a waste of our time.  Please edit your question and add a photo of your connections.

Comment: @joan. Please see. I have added images. Thank you.

Comment: So, the red wire is ground, right?

Comment: so, on the LED, which pin is the anode and which is the cathode

Comment: Anode (+) is connected to the resistor.

Comment: Yes. and LED is lighting up when connected to the 3.3v pin.

Comment: Quite simply, you appear to be connecting to the wrong pins - get rid of the IDC cable and directly connect.

Comment: In other words use a much smaller resistor.  Try 330 ohms instead.

Comment: I am totally new. Are there any chance to not light up on 7th pin when it was working fine with the 1st one (3.3v)?

Comment: @JaromandaX You might need to get your eyes checked - there is no such thing as a 56MΩ resistor (at least outside specialist items)

Comment: Yes! it's 560 ohm. Updated in the question description. with tolerance: 5%

Comment: The IDC cable will probably be swapping the odd and even pins.  So you think you are connecting to pin 1 (3V3) but you are in fact connecting to pin 2 (5V).  Check with a meter.

Comment: Hey! It just started working. I don't know how? It was not working first. I left it and went to washroom. I came back and it started working.... 
Thank you so much.

Comment: The solution is what given in the answer. I was using round pins. When I connected with flat blades everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other possible issues, you are using cables with round pins to connect to an IDC connector.

IDC connectors have a flat blade, designed to connect to a square pin.

Using round pins often results in unreliable contacts.

Use proper DuPont connectors to connect to the Pi directly, **OR** use one of the boards designed for IDC connectors on your breadboard.